# How to find a needle in database sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have query which search for database, that is

```
 $linkcdb = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT wp_link_factor WHERE wp_link_chk = %s", $u));
```

where `$u = is nay link;`
for example;

```
$u = www.kaka.com
$u = popopo.com
$u = http://jajaja.com
```

I have a data base in which `www, http and .com` is in the column of table and the column name is `wp_link_chk`

Now the problem I am facing is the user input is a complete link like `www.example.com` while in database I had only `.com, http and www`

What I want is that how I compare my complete sentence and see if the sentence have needle http, or www or .com in it ?

The function that do this is `stristr($u,'http')` so how I am going to use this functionality in data base, I mean how i am going to check the column of wp_link_chk as a needle against my sentence ?

Comment: You could use [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate). Or something like `WHERE %s like concat('%',wp_link_chk,'%')` (probably not a good idea).

Comment: I don't know what `$wpdb` is in your case, but preparing and executing queries via [PDOs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) does not work like in your code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the MySQL function [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) you could use something like

```
... WHERE LOCATE( wp_link_chk, :userInput ) > 0
```

Edit: Note that this approach may of course return multiple records, for instance if `"http://www.example.com"` is matched against `"http"`, `"www"`, and `".com"`.

Comment: seems perfect, but as you said getting a array now well the array actually helps thank alot.

Comment: You may be able to use an aggregate function to get the single result you need, like for example `SELECT MAX( wp_link_factor ) FROM ... WHERE ...`.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the closest way to match these is to use the mysql LIKE function.

The actual statement would be something like

```
SELECT wp_link_factor WHERE wp_link_chk LIKE %www.example.com%
```

But since you are using wordpress prepared statements, use it like this:

```
$linkcdb = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT wp_link_factor WHERE wp_link_chk LIKE %s", '%' . $u . '%'));
```

**-- UPDATE --**

For the sake of completion, you can use REGEXP matching to select rows that contains either http, www or .com in the wp_link_chk column using the following query.

```
SELECT wp_link_factor WHERE wp_link_chk REGEXP '(http)|(www)|(\.com)'
```

Comment: I think the OP wants it just the other way round: check if `wp_link_chk` is in, e.g., "www.example.com".

Comment: does it have any draw backs, or it search whole string and see if it is matching or not ?

Comment: LIKE is a core MySQL function that allows for Regular Expression matching. Read the docs here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

and here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: I just have look at the documents it not at all what I want, I said in my question the user put the whole website, like www.kaka.com and I want to match the database column that contains only .com www and http etc to it as a needle. while this function search for the whole thing.